# How can I use Split( ) instead of componentsSeparatedByString( ) ?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I have the same result by using the Split( ) method instead of componentsSeparatedByString( ) method:

```
public func className(obj: Any) -> String {
  return toString(obj.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Swift 1.2
public func className(obj: Any) -> String {
    return split(toString(obj.dynamicType)) { $0 == "." }.last!
}

// Swift 2.0
public func className(obj: Any) -> String {
    return String(obj.dynamicType)
                .characters.split { $0 == "." }
                .map { String($0) }
                .last!
}

print(className(42))            // Int
print(className("Hello world")) // String
print(className(1.0))           // Double
print(className([1,2,3]))       // Array<Int>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `return split(toString(obj.dynamicType)) { $0 == "." }.last!`, although force-unwrapping `last` seems unwise.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I came up with this solution:

```
public func className(obj: Any) -> String {
  return split(toString(obj.dynamicType),maxSplit: Int.max,allowEmptySlices:false, isSeparator: { $0 == "."}).last!
}
```